# Can DBContext Generator generate mappings from the edmx file?

Tags: entity-framework, t4, dbcontext

I have an old database (with terribly named tables and columns) and an entity framework data model where I have mapped the table and column names from the database to sensible names.

When running the DBContext generator on the model the context is created with the names from the model but the column and table mappings are not preserved. Is it possible to auto-generate these mappings?

I realise it can be done manually in the OnModelCreating method [like this.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx)

Comment: What do you mean by *the column and table mappings are not preserved8*? If you define mapping in EDMX file and add DbContext Generator T4 template it should not alter your EDMX file.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka The EDMX file stays the same. I mean they aren't pulled through to the DBContext...The DBContext just has the DBSets with the names that were saved in the EDMX file and therefore the DBContext can't be used with the database as the names in the actual database differ from what's in the DBContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using EDMX file your generated context will not contain the mapping. EDMX file is the mapping and when you compile the application this file is decomposed into three resources used for mapping at runtime.